# CSV import in EXCEL: decimal separators dissapear, but only on some numbers.

Tags: excel, csv, import, decimal

I have a problem when importing CSV files in excel: excel refuses to display the decimal seperator "." . so, 1.23456789, for instance, is displayed as 123456789. I tried the following:

-language settings are US now, decimal seperator set as "." 
-cell options > text. now it displays 1.23456789E17 in the cell, but in the formula bar it keeps on displaying 123456789.

I cannot "mislead" excel making the CSV file a txt file, since i have to use the CSV file in other programs.

Comment: rename the CSV file to *.txt and use File->Open in Excel to get the import wizard. There is a phase where you can see what's wrong with data sample present. Does it give you a hint what is the difference between some-good-numbers and some-bad-numbers? If not then add the troublesome piece of CSV to your question

Comment: sorry for my incredibly late answer. The wizard does not give any clue as to what goes wrong. A similar problem occurs in R statistics, see next post.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927537/importing-csv-us-formatted-numbers-in-excel-with-localisation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing CSV US formatted numbers in Excel with localisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927537/importing-csv-us-formatted-numbers-in-excel-with-localisation)

Answer (score 0):

Let us try an experiment:

Using NotePad create a file whose sole contents is:

**1.23456789**

save this file as x.csv on your desktop.

Double-click the file

What do you see??

Comment: @pnuts thank you......there must be something in the Poster's Excel environment that is corrupting the cells.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I realize that I am a complete bitch by replying so late. Some other projects received priority, so did not have time to work on this one.

Comment: I tried your example, and i see 123456789 in excel. The problem is not only with excel, but seems to be in my computer somewhere else. I'm using R statistics now, and found out the following: when i open the original datasets, the values are correctly displayed, but their class is "factor" instead of "numeric". When i change the class to "numeric" the decimal separator disappears.