# Importing CSV US formatted numbers in Excel with localisation?

Tags: excel, csv, localization

I have a .csv file with the following values:

```
1488201602.653, 8.304700E-04, 3.079498E-03
1488201603.107, 8.677357E-04, 2.856719E-03
1488201821.012, 7.071995E-04, 4.147542E-03
```

As visible from the snippet, the numbers are in differing format: the first column has a full number, and a period `.` as a decimal point separator. The second and third columns have numbers in scientific notation, except a capital `E` is used, and again a period is used for the decimal separator; there are no thousands separator in any of the values.

When I try to import this in a Danish localized version of Excel 2016, what I get is something like this:

[image]

So, I'm apparently getting a ton of thousand separators as periods `.` in the first column, however, if I select the first number, the formula field shows this:

[image]

... meaning, the number that was originally `1488201602.653` in the `.csv` file, now became interpreted as the integer `1488201602653`, which is completely wrong.

For the sevcond and third columns, if I select a number, then the formula field shows:

[image]

... meaning, the number that was originally `8.304700E-04` in the `.csv` file, then became `8,30E+02` in the cell, shown as `830,47` in the `.csv`, which is - again - completely wrong.

How can I persuade Excel to import the data in the `.csv` file, which in USA or C locale, in its proper numeric values, so they are shown properly under Danish localisation (that is, `1488201602,653` and `8,304700e-04`)?

Comment: I had the same problem in italian localized excel 2016. Even changing the excel decimal place separator to dot (.) does not work: 1.1, 2.2 is imported as 11 12. Crazy

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a manual way to handle this issue, but it would still be nice to know if there is an automatic one.

First, get and install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.3.html) if you don't already have it.

Then, note that:

- Under US (or "C" language) localization, there is no thousands separator (i.e. it is an empty string, "") - under Danish localization, the thousands separator is period "`.`"
- Under US (or "C" language) localization, the decimal separator is a period "`.`" - under Danish localization, the decimal separator is comma "`,`"
- The Danish localization demands that the E-notation exponent is written as miniscule letter `e`, not as a capital letter `E`

Then, open your `.csv` file in Notepad++, and possibly save it as a copy under a different filename. Then, do the following replacements in this order:

- Search for comma `,` -> replace with semicolon `;` (replace all)
- Search for period `.` -> replace with comma `,` (replace all)
- Search for capital `E` -> replace with miniscule `e` (replace all)

Then save the file, and import it in Excel. When importing in Excel, remember to specify the semicolon `;` as a CSV field separator - and the numbers (at least as per the OP example) should be read-in and interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would try like this with VBA (not tested) :

```
Sub ImportCSVFile()
    Dim xFileName As Variant
    xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", , "Choose CSV", , False)
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Dim rG As Range
    Set rG = wS.Range("A1")

    Dim QT As QueryTable
    With wS
        Set QT = .QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, rG)
        With QT
            '''Preserve initial format
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            '''Select the delimiter
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            '''Choose refresh options
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .SaveData = True
            '''Import the data
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With 'QT
        '''Force the formatting
        Call .Columns("1:3").Replace(".", ",")
    End With 'wS
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, @R3uK - I guess, the intent of this macro is to be assigned to a button (as demonstrated in [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx) or other tutorials), and when clicking it, you get a file open/import dialog, is that correct? I will eventually try this code, and if it works, I'll accept this answer...

Comment: @sdaau : Yes, you can add a button and assign the code to it, or simply launch it in VBE. This will add a sheet the sheet every time you run it, but you can tune it if you don't like this behavior. The part that I can't test easily it the last one regarding the format of the imported numbers, so you'll probably have to improve that part. ;)