# Location causes incorrect placement of separators in Excel during file import

Tags: excel, vba, import, localization, separator

I import large amounts of data into Excel. These are previously reduced in quantity from 100 Hz to 1 Hz by a third-party program to reduce work and load time. However, during this reduction process, decimal and thousands separators are swapped, probably because the software is designed in a different language.

Original (Example line):

```
009 090308.510 +2475.77145123 -0091.51682637 070.530 271.89 +0168.67 +0001.13 -8.485680E-04 0.000000 +4.625850E-04 +2.679440E+36 -2.544081E-29 +2.658468E+36
```

Processed by third party program:

```
009 090308,510 +2475,77145123 -0091,51682637 070,530 271.89 +00168,67 +001,130 0,000000 -8.485680E-04 +4.625850E-04 +2.679440E+36 -2.544081E-29 +2.658468E+36
```

As can be seen, some separators are swapped by the program, but others are not. If I now apply my import code to both formats, I get the following results:

Original:

```
9 90308.51 2475.771 -91.5168 70.53 271.89 168.67 1.13 -8.49E-04 0 4.63E-04 2.68E+36 -2.54E-29 2.66E+36
```

Processed:

```
9 90,308,510 247,577,145,123 -9,151,682,637 40,530 271.89 +00168,67 1,130 0,000000 -8.49E-04 4.63E-04 2.68E+36 -2.54E-29 2.66E+36
```

For understanding here the code for import:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub fileImporter()
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim fPath As Variant
    Dim FSO
    Dim Data
    Dim arr, tmp, output
    Dim file, fileName As String
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select files to import"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "VBO Files", "*.vbo" 'VBO Files are opened and handled like Text Files
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For Each fPath In .SelectedItems
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
                fileName = FSO.GetFilename(fPath)
                Set Data = FSO.OpentextFile(fPath)
                file = Data.readall
                Data.Close
                
                
                arr = Split(file, vbCrLf)
                ReDim output(UBound(arr), 50)
                For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    tmp = Split(arr(x), " ")
                    For y = 0 To UBound(tmp)
                        output(x, y) = tmp(y)
                    Next
                Next
                
                Set newSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
                newSht.Name = fileName
                
                Sheets(fileName).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output) + 1, UBound(output, 2)) = output
            Next
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

The record of the processed file is not separated rudimentarily correctly and reasonably.  I have also already tried using

```
With Application
     .DecimalSeparator = "."
     .ThousandsSeparator = ","
     .UseSystemSeparator = False
End With
```

but that did not work either. Or rather, it changed the separators, but the result stayed the same. The numbers were not separated at the correct places.
I found a similar question here ([Importing CSV US formatted numbers in Excel with localisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927537/importing-csv-us-formatted-numbers-in-excel-with-localisation)), which seems to be the same problem. But since the import function in the answer is different from mine, I am not sure how to integrate it properly.

Does someone have a idea? Maybe a way how to preserve the format while or during splitting? Or a better place to integrate the Application.DecimalSeparator argument in the given code?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

The problem could be solved by comparing system settings. Apparently, the computer was not provided with the default settings by IT and some settings of the previous owner were still present. These included a partial language change to German, as well as a permanent replacement of the decimal and thousands separators in Excel, instead of using the system separators. After correcting these settings, the program and import works without incorrect separator usage.

Comment: I also just realized, that the third party program seems to swap the order of some values, but I do not know the reason for that.

Comment: "some separators are swapped by the program, but others are not" - is this consistent?  Are the same items unaffected on each line?  If all separators aren't swapped it seems like you need to know which ones are left unchanged...

Comment: Although my answer below may help you clean up your current data, something seems just wrong. There is no reason for a program to output data using inconsistent decimal symbols. I suggest you explore both the source as well as the publisher of the third party program you are using to ascertain where the problem arises, and then have it corrected at that point.

Comment: @TimWilliams It seems to be consistent. The only separators that are not swapped are the heading, which is given as a degree number, and the values, which are exponential.

Comment: If you know the indexes in each line where you need to replace `,` with `.` then couldn't you do that while filling the `output` array?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The change of different separators for different values could be clarified by the manufacturer. The data sets contain data recorded by a GPS, as well as values supplemented by other devices. However, the program only processes those from the GPS and ignores the others. In connection with the incorrect settings of my computer, this results in an inconsistent change of the separators.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- `Data => Get &Transform => From Text/Csv`
- When the initial dialog opens, ensure `Space` is selected as the Delimiter
- Select `Transform Data`
- Select `Home=>Advanced Editor`
- Replace the code after your `Source` line with the code below (after `Source`)

***Edit change in swapping algorithm***

- It appears by examination that

  - All columns are numeric
  - Separators are **swapped** on the columns where there is a **comma**
  - All other columns have the separators **not swapped**

*If those assumptions are not correct, some changes may need to occur*

*If there are swapped and non-swapped values in a single column, I would suggest you develop another method to sample your data, else you would have to check every single cell*

***M Code edited to implement change in algorithm above***
***M Code edited to check first 200 table rows for commas instead of just first row***

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\decimals.txt"),
        [Delimiter=" ", Columns=14, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

//Swapped separators = numbers with commas
// check only the first 200 rows, for efficiency

    #"Check Table" = Table.Buffer(Table.FirstN(Source, List.Max({Table.RowCount(Source), 200}))),
    Swapped = List.Accumulate(Table.ColumnNames(#"Check Table"), {}, (state, current)=>
        if  List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Check Table", current), each Text.Contains(_,",")))
            then state & {current} else state),
    notSwapped = List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Check Table"),Swapped),

//Set the data types appropriately
    #"Type Not Swapped"= Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, 
        List.Transform(notSwapped, each {_, type number}),"en-US"),

    #"Type Swapped" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Type Not Swapped", 
        List.Transform(Swapped, each {_, type number}),"da-DK")
in
    #"Type Swapped"
```

***Original Data***

```
| 009   | 090308,510    | +2475,77145123    | -0091,51682637    | 070,530   | 271.89    | +00168,67     | +001,130  | 0,000000  | -8.485680E-04     | +4.625850E-04     | +2.679440E+36     | -2.544081E-29     | +2.658468E+36     |
```

[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: There are no exchanged and non-exchanged separators in one column. The values are swapped and not swapped consistently. However, the complete data set does not contain permanent entries in each column. With the exception of the pretext, a cell in the columns can be either empty or have a numeric content.

Comment: @Henir did you try my solution? It should work unless it is necessary to check more than the cell in the first row to determine. Let me know. If that is the case, only a small modification would be necessary. It's clearly works on the data set you provided

Comment: @Henir I have edited the code so it will check the first 200 rows of a table, looking for the `comma`.  Let me know how it works on your data set.

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting back to you, but I've had a bit of a vacation. It turns out, as you noted, that the problem had a different origin than the code. Although the computer was supposed to be fully reset by our IT before I got it, settings in Excel and language settings in Windows were still changed. Parts of Windows were still in German. In Excel, the system separator adoption was disabled and replaced with permanent. I only noticed this today with a colleague. My previous solutions now work fine.